# Import error while the application is running in another Pc

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I created an executable on Windows platform by `cx_freeze`, the exe file run successfully in my PC, it works also in another PC but when I try to use some features in my application, I find this error in my log file:

> File "C:\Users\xxxx\venv\mpetools\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 448, in init

This is the block of the error in `pytables.py`:

```
try:
    import tables # noqa
except:
 #ImportError as ex: # pragma: no cover
 raise ImportError('HDFStore requires PyTables, "{ex}" problem '
'importing'.format(ex=str(ex)))
```

PS: The `pytables.pyc` and the folder tables exist in my build folder.

My PC:

- OS：Windows 10 64bit
- Python：3.6.8
- Miniconda3: 4.7.12
- cx_freeze: 6.0

The other PC:

- OS：Windows 10 64bit

How can I resolve this problem please?

Comment: Are you usre the 3rd party libraries you are importing exist in both PCs? Do they have the same version?

Comment: Python wasn't created to create .exe files and all tools for this are not ideal. Sometimes they don't know what module it has to add to .exe - it can be problem with python module but also with C/C++ libraries used by Python module. You would have to test program on fresh Windows without Python and without other libraries and if it could find some module/library then you should add it manually to configuration file which you use to run cx_freeze.

Comment: `pytables` can be only wrapper for some C/C++ module `tables` which you would have to also add to .exe